# How to install Device Manager and Emulator Manager for Tizen Studio?

Tags: tizen, tizen-studio

I'm trying to install the Device and Emulator Manager for Tizen Studio on Windows 10 64 bit but I keep running into the same issue no matter what repo I use. Here is the error log:

```
Start to install 'Emulator'.
The target packages to install:
  [emulator-control-panel-common, emulator-common-lib, emulator-supplements, emulator-manager, emulator-storages, Emulator]
Start to download the target packages.
Waiting for finishing the downloads of the packages...
Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.wrapExceptionWithGeneralInstallException(InstallController.java:577)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:652)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:537)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.Install.InstallProcess.run(InstallProcess.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot download the package file.
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.downloadPackageFile(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:350)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.downloadPackage(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:206)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.call(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:99)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.call(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:63)
    ... 4 more
  Caused by: org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: The downloaded size of the file is not same as the actual size of it.
    at org.tizen.manager.util.Downloader.downloadFile(Downloader.java:285)
    at org.tizen.manager.util.Downloader.download(Downloader.java:137)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.DownloaderCallable.call(DownloaderCallable.java:68)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.DownloaderCallable.call(DownloaderCallable.java:40)
    ... 4 more
Recalculating the install state by failure...
Refreshing the install state of other packages...
Failed to install... Emulator


Start to install 'Device-Manager'.
The target packages to install:
  [device-manager-product, Device-Manager]
Start to download the target packages.
Waiting for finishing the downloads of the packages...
Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.wrapExceptionWithGeneralInstallException(InstallController.java:577)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:652)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:537)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.Install.InstallProcess.run(InstallProcess.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot download the package file.
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.downloadPackageFile(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:350)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.downloadPackage(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:206)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.call(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:99)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.ManagerableDownloaderCallable.call(ManagerableDownloaderCallable.java:63)
    ... 4 more
  Caused by: org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: The downloaded size of the file is not same as the actual size of it.
    at org.tizen.manager.util.Downloader.downloadFile(Downloader.java:285)
    at org.tizen.manager.util.Downloader.download(Downloader.java:137)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.DownloaderCallable.call(DownloaderCallable.java:68)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.download.DownloaderCallable.call(DownloaderCallable.java:40)
    ... 4 more
Recalculating the install state by failure...
Refreshing the install state of other packages...
Failed to install... Device-Manager
```

I haven't been able to find any similar issues while searching on Google or Stack Overflow. It keeps saying 'The downloaded size of the file is not same as the actual size of it.'

Comment: Try with " http://brazil.sdk-dl.tizen.org/sdk/tizenstudio " or " http://usa.sdk-dl.tizen.org/sdk/tizenstudio " as package repository. I guess it may work.

Comment: Try re-installing Tizen Studio again, check your firewall settings

Comment: Also check Java Development Kit (JDK) 8 is installed. Have a look on
prerequisites for the Tizen Studio: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to delete the cache folders in

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\.package-manager
```